# validationQuery (select 1) running 24/7 without being specified?

Tags: tomcat, select, datasource, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our DBA is saying that there is a "SELECT 1" query running 24/7 against our snowflake database but we did not specify validation query at all.

We are using tomcat data source but we did not specific datasource.validation-query in the properties file.

```
datasource.url: jdbc:snowflake://mytestserver:443/? 
warehouse=testwh&db=test&schema=mytest&CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=true
datasource.username: xxxx
datasource.password: xxxx

datasource.type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
datasource.initial-size: 1
datasource.min-idle: 1
datasource.max-idle: 10
datasource.max-active: 10
```

Is there any default connection pool properties  that control when validation queries  run and at what interval and run SELECT 1 query ? Can we disable the SELECT 1 query somehow or make it once a day ?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties.setValidationQuery(String)` and when hit, inspect the stack to find out who is responsible for setting a validationQuery. (implied it is the Tomcat JDBC pool who invokes the query)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why a validationQuery would be running without configuration. To the best of my knowledge, Tomcat sets this to NULL by default. You could try explicitly specifying the validationQuery and validationInterval in the data source definition to work around the issue. I also always recommend using the latest version of the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

As one of my colleagues found out that our Java Spring Boot applications typically include a library called Spring Boot Actuator, which includes several “out of the box” health check features. One of these is for checking the health of a javax.sql.Datasource object, and it does that by executing a SELECT  1  query.

solution:

management.health.db.enabled: false